# Getting jsonschema jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: Schema is not of type 'object', 'boolean',

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am writing a python program for validating json schema with sample JSON and I am using a package called jsonschema for JSON validation. When I run my code I am getting the error. It is showing that there is some is some issue in certain segment of JSON schema.But, I can't make out what exactly the error means "jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError:[Schema] is not of type 'object', 'boolean' " Below is the Python code:-

```
 # import jsonSchema_validate
 # from jsonSchema_validate import validate
from jsonschema import validate
schema = {"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/drafts/2020-12/schema","type":"object","properties":{"responseCode":{"type":"integer"},"message":{"type":"string"},"returnValueType":{"type":"string"},"returnValue":{"type":"object","properties":{"configuration":{"type":"object","properties":{"adminLocked":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"maxNumberOfMACAddresses":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"port":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"qosProfile":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"operational":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}},"accessConnection":{"type":"object","properties":{"accessTechnology":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"linkUp":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"optical":{"type":"object","properties":{"upStream":{"type":"object","properties":{"waveLength":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"signalPower":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"inRange":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"bytes":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}},"downStream":{"type":"object","properties":{"waveLength":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"signalPower":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"inRange":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"bytes":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}}}},"lineError":{"type":"object","properties":{"upStream":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"downStream":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}}}},"terminationPoint":{"type":"object","properties":{"cpeType":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"serial":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"cpeUp":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"ethernet":{"type":"object","properties":{"linkUp":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"bitrate":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"fullDuplex":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"maxPortSpeed":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}},"upTime":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}},"rf":{"type":"object","properties":{"outputSignalStrength":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"filter":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"optical":{"type":"object","properties":{"downStream":{"type":"object","properties":{"waveLength":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"signalPower":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"inRange":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"boolean"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}}}}}},"vLans":{"type":"array","items":[{"type":"object","properties":{"cVlan":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"integer"}}},"learnedMACAddresses":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"items":[{"properties":{"mac":{"type":"string"},"onPOI":{"properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"boolean"}},"type":"object"}},"type":"object"}],"type":"array"}}},"multicast":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"boolean"}}},"multicastSnoop":{"properties":{"items":[{"type":"string"}],"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"type":"array"}},"tagged":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"boolean"}}},"tVlan":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"integer"}}},"whsid":{"type":"object","properties":{"statusCode":{"type":"integer"},"value":{"type":"string"}}}}}]},"poi":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"sVlan":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"integer"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}},"fPoi":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"type":"string"},"statusCode":{"type":"integer"}}}}}}}}}

validate(instance = {
        "message": "7e",
        "responseCode": -558638,
        "returnValue": {
            "accessConnection": {
                "accessTechnology": {
                    "statusCode": -798758,
                    "value": "<\"\n!wrOJ,"
                },
                "lineError": {
                    "downStream": {
                        "value": -738597
                    }
                }
            },
            "configuration": {
                "adminLocked": {
                    "statusCode": 195229,
                    "value": "HM.7W0zhsZ"
                },
                "maxNumberOfMACAddresses": {
                    "statusCode": 495669,
                    "value": -800730
                },
                "operational": {},
                "port": {
                    "statusCode": -672240
                },
                "qosProfile": {}
            },
            "poi": {
                "fPoi": {
                    "value": "B}Hfm"
                },
                "id": {
                    "statusCode": 260531,
                    "value": "<G8|r"
                }
            },
            "rf": {
                "filter": {
                    "statusCode": 251614,
                    "value": "jYE"
                },
                "optical": {}
            },
            "terminationPoint": {
                "cpeType": {
                    "statusCode": -896729,
                    "value": "G'?\n"
                },
                "cpeUp": {
                    "statusCode": 606944
                },
                "ethernet": {
                    "bitrate": {
                        "statusCode": -318966
                    },
                    "linkUp": {},
                    "maxPortSpeed": {}
                },
                "serial": {
                    "statusCode": 365503,
                    "value": "\rv?xkkb"
                },
                "upTime": {}
            },
            "vLans": [
            ]
        },
        "returnValueType": "&~857\rS"
    }, schema = schema)
# true
```

Below is the error received :

```
   PS C:\Users\abc> & C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe "c:/abc backup/D DRIVE DATA/Python Codes/jsonSchema_validate.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/abc backup/D DRIVE DATA/Python Codes/jsonSchema_validate.py", line 638, in <module>
    }, schema=schema)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 1117, in validate
    cls.check_schema(schema)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 231, in check_schema
    raise exceptions.SchemaError.create_from(error)
jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: [{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'cVlan': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'integer'}}}, 'learnedMACAddresses': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'items': [{'properties': {'mac': {'type': 'string'}, 'onPOI': {'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'boolean'}}, 'type': 'object'}}, 'type': 'object'}], 'type': 'array'}}}, 'multicast': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'boolean'}}}, 'multicastSnoop': {'properties': {'items': [{'type': 'string'}], 'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'type': 'array'}}, 'tagged': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'boolean'}}}, 'tVlan': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'integer'}}}, 'whsid': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'statusCode': {'type': 'integer'}, 'value': {'type': 'string'}}}}}] is not of type 'object', 'boolean'


PS C:\Users\abc>
```

Can you please let me know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `items` takes a schema, not an array of schemas. A schema is either an object or a boolean. You're getting the error because the value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have also declared an invalid metaschema.

This is the correct one to use.

```json
 "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
```

Comment: Thank you guys,. it appears like my schema declaration was wrong as mentioned by jeremy